# Getting a Property of a Property with PropertyGrids

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I'm trying to use PropertyGrids to allow users of my program to interact with C# objects. Pictured below is an example of what this looks like:

[image]

The treeview to the left lists instances of my WallType class. WallType's properties include Lumber objects, another of my classes. Say I want to change the grade of a Lumber property from 2 to 3. When the user makes this change I want to prompt them with an "are you sure" prompt. If the user says no, I want to revert back to the original value of 2 which this code is supposed to do

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This wall (" + wall.ToString() + ") has been manually edited. Regenerating it will reset those changes and the wall will go back to how it looks by default. Press Yes to continue or No to cancel regenerating this wall", "Regeneration Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

if (result == DialogResult.No) //Cancelling if user does not want to regenerate wall
{
    var item = e.ChangedItem;
    var propertyName = item.PropertyDescriptor.Name;
    PropertyInfo pi = this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

    var oldValue = e.OldValue;
    pi.SetValue(this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject, oldValue, null);
    return;
}
```

The problem with this code is that it checks my WallType class for the property Grade instead of the inner property's class of Lumber. I can't hard code to check a specific property because there are many properties of many different types. How can I change this code to check the inner properties' classes instead of just the WallType class?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of all involved classes, and how do they relate